# Updating values in a list that is within a list

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I have a list of objects and each object has a property that is a list of another object. Within this logic I'm casting the first object from a base class to one of it's inheriting classes.

It's this final list I want to make my changes to.

I've tried a few things already and I can see stepping through that the logic is executing but the finished product is always unchanged.

I've tried using linq:

```
Object1BaseObjectList
.Cast<Object1InheritedClass>()
.ToList()
.ForEach(e => 
    e.Object2List
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(p => p.boolValue = true));
```

And I've tried some more conventional code:

```
foreach (Object1InheritedClass object1 in Object1BaseObjectList)
{
    foreach (Object2Class object2 in object1.Object2List)
    {
         object2.boolValue = true;
    }
}
```

Like I said the end result for both of these is no change. Anyone have any ideas as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: Did u commit the changes??

Comment: `Object2` is struct or class?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy It's a class

Comment: You should provide a complete example - ie one that we can run the code to see the behaviour you are having problems with. As it is to run your code we would need to make our own versions of several of your objects and we may well end up making assumptions about them that are not true. At a glance your code looks sound. I assume you've confirmed with a debugger that the line `object2.boolValue = true;` is definitely being hit?

Comment: Please Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Just answering for the sake of closing this out. The information I provided was not enough to answer the question. Turns out the issue was being caused by the second list being declared as an IEnumerable. Changing it to a list corrected it. I'm assuming this was because IEnumerable wasn't creating a deep copy.